# How to add fragment on click on Action Bar Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment

I am using the AppCompat library for my android app. I am trying to add Action Bar Tab that I have done now I could not add the fragment on click on `ActionBar Tabs`. Here in below code, there I have two tabs on click on them I want to inflate the fragment

Any idea for this ??

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // create first tab
        ActionBar.Tab tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Free apps")
                .setTabListener(this);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);

        // create second tab
        tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Paid apps")
                .setTabListener(this);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bar_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_bar_search:
                mSearchView.setIconified(false);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
            // first tab

        } else {
            // second tab
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, import [this TabListener](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/8b9f9ec29582afd4d138) to your project instead of implementing `ActionBar.TabListener` in your Activity. Then in your layout `activity_main` make sure you have a fragment container like so

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Then it's easy, add tabs to your actionbar like this:

```
Tab tab1 = actionBar
        .newTab()
        ...
        .setTabListener(new SupportFragmentTabListener<CustomFragment>(R.id.container, this,
                    "first", CustomFragment.class));
```

If you want to learn more, i.e. how to style your tabs check [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ActionBar-Tabs-with-Fragments)